# How to consume a .net4.7 app from .net core 2.0

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

I have a .net core test app that's referencing a .net framework 4.7.1 project. I've updated the project file of the .net core project so that it looks like this...

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net471</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.3.0-preview-20170628-02" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\PushNotifications\PushNotifications.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

When I debug a test, I get..

> Catastrophic failure: System.TypeInitializationException: The type
>   initializer for 'Xunit.DiaSession' threw an exception. --->
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Reflection.TypeExtensions, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

Adding System.Reflection.TypeExtensions to either project has no effect.

What else do I need to do?

Comment: You shouldn't do so at all. Why cannot you test a .NET 4.x reference in a .NET 4.x project?

Comment: Because I was hoping to use the net471 from a netcoreapp2 website. Thought I’d prove the concept.